# Unity3D Hololens access Windows.Storage.KnownFolders

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I need to access the PicturesLibrary fodler on the Hololens. 
Docs state that you can do that by "Windows.Storage.PicturesLibrary"

But I can not import the namespace "Windows" in my Unity project because its not included in UWP, also it should be possible.
I am using the Unity3D 2019.2 with .net 4.x

How can I load pictures from the folder the right way with the HoloLens?

I tried some examples from similar questions but none of them worked, like eg.g:

```
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WINRT_10_0
return Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.Path;                 
#else
```

Answer (score 1):

@crani have you set the UWP [App Capability declaratio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations)n for PicturesLibrary access?

note that the docs mention that the capability provides access to "enumerate" the files in the library. Path is typically going to be an empty string for any of the KnowFolder types.

You will need to do something like this:

```
StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> pictures = await picturesFolder.GetFilesAsync();
```

So if you wrap something similar in an #if directive you should be able to access the files, but the path is abstracted from the app as a storage folder.

Comment: Hi, yes I have set that, the problem is I can not  import "Windows.Storage.KnownFolder", I even see a warning in Visual Studio that the binary is missing. But I don't unserstand why because it should be included in UWP

How would you import "KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary" in a normal UWP Unity project the right way?

Comment: If you create a new UWP project in Visual Studio it will install a NuGet package for UWP platform references:  Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform which I believe references the assemblies that would include the Windows.Storage namespace.

Are you adding your "Using Windows.Storage" to the UWP project that gets generated by Unity when you build?

Comment: Thanks for your help.
When I build for UWP in Unity, it generates a VS project were I can deploy to my HoloLens. Do I have to add a reference to that NuGet package manually?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the import in an `#if` statement as well.
This is what I am using for the HoloLens 2 in C#:

```
#if UNITY_WSA_10_0 && ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
using Windows.Storage;
#endif
```

---

You will also need to ensure that the correct Capabilities are checked in the settings of the solution you are building (or wherever you build from), so the Hololens device knows what the app will try to gain access to.

In Visual Studio, the Capabiliities settingscan be found under Solution Explorer > Project > open Package.appxmanifest > Capabiliites tab.

In Unity, it is under Project Settings > Player > Publishing Settings > Capabilities.

You would select PicturesLibrary, Objects3D, or the checkbox corresponding to the folder you are attempting to access.

Unity failed to update the Package.appxmanifest in VS for me, so I had to edit it myself.

---

(Late answer, I know, but I hope it helps those who wander to this question!)